# Cucumber Step Definition Regex Exclude

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

I need some help with a regular expression in a Cucumber step definition file. Many of my steps are of the type:

```
Given I am on the search page
```

I use this general pattern for most of my step definitions, and use the default Webrat regex to pick it up that looks like this:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
     visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

The problem is that I need to handle a page titled 'results' differently, and I do not know how to modify the above regex to exclude lines that say 'Given I am on the results page'.

Comment: More specific regex (for the result page) should win therefore you don't need to change the generic regex.

Comment: That was actually one of the first things I tried, but I still get an error about both regex's matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead to resolve this one:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (?!the results)(.+)$/ do |page_name|
    p page_name
end

Given /^I am on the results page$/ do
   p 'We matched the results page'
end
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up not using the regular expression, and instead writing individual regexes for each case, but I just tried this and it definitely works.